# What is the differences between to install docker-compose by binary or by pip install

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, rhel

We have two option that we can use in order to install the docker-compose

We already installed docker , and now we want to install docker compose on **production environment**

One option is by binary docker-compose

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

the second option is by pip as the following

```
$ yum install epel-release
Install python-pip
$ yum install -y python-pip
Then install Docker Compose:
$ pip install docker-compose
```

Are the first option that installed the docker-compose by binary is a ***good enough*** as the docker-compose that installed by PIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-74-curl-vs-pip-for-installing-docker-compose

But in reality it no difference I suppose, I personally prefer to install docker-compose from package(what probably is not recommended cause it usually very old version), but it works well for me.

```
apt-get install docker-compose
```